# I file a bug unmarshal when deploying promethues-ms teams

Tags: prometheus

I get the following log when trying to deploy the prometheus-msteams application deployment. I indicate this in case someone else introduces him at some time.

App: prometheus-msteams (deployment)

```
{"caller":"main.go:174","err":"yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 1: cannot unmarshal !!seq into main.PromTeamsConfig","ts":"2022-10-12T18:24:37.97854431Z"}
```

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the code of prometheus-msteams

https://github.com/prometheus-msteams/prometheus-msteams/blob/master/cmd/server/main.go

PromTeamsConfig has to do with the structure of the connector. I went to the configmap file where I have the connectors, and I had a syntax error

before:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiQBl.png)
After monitoring:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK0ky.png)

and with this solve the problem

Comment: Update: the main thing I was missing was the "connectors:" and I had indentation problems.

`data:
  connectors.yaml: |  
   connectors:
      - xxxx: "https://..."
       - yyyy: "https://..."`